# Поплыла разметка в комментариях с кодом

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, комментарии

Имеется [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470477/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-cookies-jsoup) где есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470546/238742), и под ним [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470477/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-cookies-jsoup/1470546?noredirect=1#comment2632458_1470546) (сейчас во всяком случае):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не знаю получится ли такое быстро починить, но тем не менее думаю что проблема не только в этом вопросе.

### Update:

Из страницы пользователя тоже не очень красиво показывает в вкладке `Активность-Реакции`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разметка блоков кода в комментариях никогда на stackoverflow и не работала (в отличие от хэшкода). Считайте, что это фича, а не баг - блоки кода нужно размещать в вопросах или ответах, но не в комментариях. В крайнем случае, если нужно что-то уточнить, придется использовать pastebin или другой похожий сервис.

Comment: Ну тогда ладно) значит так и задумано)